# React router dom won't show component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm trying to create page where first user have to login then it will take to the main lay out component that is `Home.js` component, in `Home.js` have `Route` that show default page that is `<Dashboard/>`. But for some reason it just won't show the Dashboard component.

Make it clear, here's the code:

App.js

```
import Login from './Component/Login';
import Register from './Component/Register.jsx'
import Home from './Component/Home'
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes,
  Route,
} from "react-router-dom";
    
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<Login />} />
          <Route path="/register" element={<Register />} />
          <Route path="*" element={<Home />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
    
export default App;
```

When the user done login, take to Home.js page which is this code:

Home.js

```
import React from "react";
import Sidebar from './Sidebar'
import Dashboard from "./Dashboard";
import Profile from "./Profile";
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import './Home.css'

function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <Sidebar/>    
      <Routes>
        <Route index element={<Dashboard />} /> // This won't show for some reason.
        <Route path="/profile" element={<Profile />} />
      </Routes>
    </>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

The code in dashboard component is only text, the code:

Dashboard.js

```
import React from 'react'

function Dashboard() {
  return (
    <div className="dashboard">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Deleniti, odio totam blanditiis nobis explicabo in repellendus laborum, quas velit corrupti dolore error minus natus fugiat alias fuga esse quo recusandae voluptatum ullam quia. Voluptatum obcaecati, mollitia suscipit ex modi quidem, placeat ratione maxime id sint alias dignissimos tempora soluta sed ab voluptates voluptatem facere velit dolor temporibus! Officiis quod illo dignissimos vitae et temporibus, iusto accusantium ipsum ex. Perspiciatis sapiente perferendis cumque corporis suscipit esse. Voluptatem laudantium quam placeat dignissimos.</p>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Dashboard
```

Does anyone know why `Dashboard` not showing?

Comment: There are two Dashboard imported, may be something wrong there 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the routed components are rendering descendent routes then the parent route should append a trailing wildcard `"*"` character to the path so the descendent routes can also be matched and rendered.

The index route of the `Home` component is already matched by `"/"` rendering the `Login` component. Move either of `Login` or `Dashboard` to another path.

Example:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} /> // <-- "/login" now
          <Route path="/register" element={<Register />} />
          <Route path="*" element={<Home />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

...

```
function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <Sidebar/>    
      <Routes>
        <Route index element={<Dashboard />} /> // <-- renders on "/" now
        <Route path="/profile" element={<Profile />} />
      </Routes>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: But is there a way so that Login Component became the default page? so when user visit  it's going to be /login not /.

Comment: @JoshLee Sure. If you want `Login` component to render on `"/"` then you'll need to move the other route. In other words, you can't have two routes that resolve to the same path. An example would be to render the dashboard as `<Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />`.